# How can I make a div occupy the rest of the screen and not get the scroll?

Tags: html, css

[image]
I want the banner to occupy all the rest of the screen, responsively on the devices. From there, the scroll starts with the other information.
I've tried using the 100% height and the automatic height, but we still didn't solve. What is the best way to resolve this?

HTML

```
  <body>

    <div class="top-bar">
      <div class="logo">Logo</div>
      <div class="menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="banner">
      <div class="banner-text">
        <div class="banner-text-items">
          <h2>Banner Text Heading</h2>
          <p>Exercitation commodo elit magna aute ad magna laboris esse in voluptate voluptate ullamco nulla deserunt.
            Esse adipisicing amet commodo ad laborum sit commodo sit sint et occaecat cillum ex occaecat. Ullamco est
            labore est sit velit nulla deserunt est labore.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
```

CSS

```
  *{margin: 0; padding: 0;}

  .banner{
    background-image: url('./fox.jpg');
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
  }

  .top-bar{
    background-color: #000;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  .logo{
    color: #fff;
    flex: 1;
    font-size: 48px;
    padding: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  .menu{
    flex: 3;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `height: 100vh` to your `.banner` css block. That should make the height 100% of the device screen.

Read more about this here: https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/

Comment: if I put 100vh it will pass and the scroll will appear, because I already have the header that takes up a little space above the banner.

Comment: then set the header to the vh equivalent. For example `header{ height:10vh } .banner{height: 90vh}`. As long as the total height of the header + banner equal 100, there should be no scroll

Comment: got it! But I am doing the header using the flexbox. Can I set a height without losing his responsiveness?

Comment: Yeah you should be fine. Flexbox sets arrangement for the elements inside a flex container, setting the height of that container shouldn't cause a problem i think

Comment: I just tested it and the flex-wrap: wrap does not increase the container with the height defined in the header.

Comment: sorry what do you mean?

Comment: in the original code you posted, i can't see `flex-wrap: wrap`

Comment: i'm not too sure how to solve this, glad i could help with the original question though